# How do you get the values of their textboxes and transfer them to richtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

How do you get the values of their textboxes and transfer them to richtextbox?

I created a windows application form that contains a button1, a richtextbox, and a webbrowser(set to facebook.)

I want this button1, that if clicked, it will then copy the values that were typed in the registration forms of facebook.com and then pastes it to the richtextbox.

These are the IDs of their text boxes.

"firstname"
  "lastname"
  "reg_email__"
  "reg_email_confirmation__"
  "reg_passwd__"
  "sex"
  "birthday_month"
 "birthday_day"
  "birthday_year"

How do you programmatically get the values that were typed in the facebook textboxes and then transfer them to richtextbox?

Comment: You'll get the classical answer [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You know that Facebook has an API, right? That would be the *right* way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with `WinForms` you can do use the `WebBrowser` control's `Document` property. It returns an object of type `HtmlDocument`. `HtmlDocument` in turn has a method `GetElementById` returning an object of type `HtmlElement`. The `OuterHtml` property finally contains the information about the textbox. Using a `Regex` expression you can extract the required info

```
HtmlElement tb = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("firstname");

string outerHtml = tb.OuterHtml;
// Yields a text which looks like this
// <INPUT id=firstname class=inputtext value=SomeValue type=text name=firstname>

string text = Regex.Match(outerHtml, @"value=(.*) type=text").Groups[1].Value;
// text => "SomeValue"
```

I would prefer to be able to access the HTML-DOM object model; however it seems to be hidden from c#.

---

EDIT:

The ComboBoxes yield a different kind of information. Note that I use the `InnerHtml` here.

```
HtmlElement cb = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sex");

string innerHtml = cb.InnerHtml;
// Yields a text which looks like this where the selected option is marked with "selected"
// <OPTION value=0>Select Sex:</OPTION><OPTION value=1>Female</OPTION><OPTION selected value=2>Male</OPTION>

Match match = Regex.Match(innerHtml, @"<OPTION selected value=(\d+)>(.*?)</OPTION>");
string optionValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
string optionText = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for someone to write the program for you? Doubt that will happen.

So, ignoring the obviously question of "why?", I'll give a few pointers. 
First, look at the View Source of the page you are intereted in. It can sometimes be easier (with fixed formats - especially with textboxes that have fixed and unique names) to scan through the html source as text and just substring out the tags with the names you want. If the textboxes are not populated at build time (i.e. the values are not in the view source), then you will probabably have to go through the DOM and access the controls individually.

Depending how and when you are accessing this page, you may well find these fields are not populated at all by FB (for the obvious security reasons) and only act as input from the user (hence my "why?" question earlier).